# How can I improve the speed of this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
u.uid as UID,
fuo.uid as FUO_UID,
fo.prid as FO_NAME
FROM 
users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN firstpoint_users_organisations fuo ON (u.uid=fuo.uid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN firstpoint_organisations fo ON (fo.nid=fuo.nid)
WHERE 
u.status=1 AND u.uid>1 
ORDER BY u.uid 
LIMIT 3;
```

And the tables:

```
users
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name             | varchar(60)      | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| status           | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

firstpoint_users_organisations
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

firstpoint_organisations
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nid      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| prid     | varchar(32)      | NO   |     |         |       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I wish to show `users.uid` and `firstpoint_organisations.prid` for every row in `users`, even though some users won't have a `prid`, in which case I show NULL (hence the left outer joins). The connection should be as follows:

```
users
uid -      firstpoint_users_organisations 
     \---->uid
           nid -          firstpoint_organisations
                \-------->nid
                          prid
```

So each user (users) has a user id (uid), and the organisation they're associated with (firstpoint_users_organisation) has a node id (nid) and stores this association. The organisation's details are then stored in firstpoint_organisations.

So every user will have a `prid`, but if they don't, show NULL.

Now, if I do an INNER JOIN on `firstpoint_users_organisations` and then on `firstpoint_organisations`, I get a good query speed (the above query runs in 0.02 seconds). But, when I switch both to LEFT OUTER JOIN, so I can get all users, `prid` or no `prid`, the above query takes ~90 seconds to run.

Is there anything I can do to speed this query up? There are approx. 70,000 rows in the `users` table, but even with LIMIT 3, the making the INNER JOIN a LEFT OUTER JOIN takes a horrible amount of time. Interestingly, the query takes the same amount of time to run with LIMIT 30, so I think there's something fundamentally wrong with my query.

EXPLAIN as requested:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                  | 13152 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fuo   | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                  |  3745 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fo    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | dbdb-dbdb_uat.fuo.nid |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please post the `EXPLAIN` of this statement.

Comment: One question to your firstpoint_users_organisations table is it possible to have 2 PRIMARY keys? It sounds actually a bit strange to me.

Comment: I've added the EXPLAIN, thankyou. 2 primary keys in the FUO table does look strange, thankyou for spotting.

Comment: You forgot a u.status in your table!

Comment: @njp: A table _cannot_ have two primary keys. But a primary key, like any other index, _can contain more than one column_.

Comment: So the problem is in the first EXPLAIN row but I have no idea why mysql is using a filesort here, because the "order by" should use the primary u.uid, or not?

Comment: @Wikunia: Aaaaah, removing the ORDER BY speeds it up remarkably. I am actually just needing a CSV dump so it doesn't need to be ordered by uid, I can do that elsewhere.

Comment: So for this examle you could use a u.uid <= 4 so {2,3,4} instead of limit 3 but I unfortunately I have no idea why he can't use the index :(

Comment: Add a `(uid,nid)` index on the 2nd table and a `(status,uid)` in the 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is pointlessly (because `uid > 1` would include all but one of the users) using the index on uid, so use the IGNORE INDEX hint for that index:

```
SELECT 
  u.uid as UID,
  fuo.uid as FUO_UID,
  fo.prid as FO_NAME
FROM users u IGNORE INDEX (uid)
LEFT JOIN firstpoint_users_organisations fuo ON u.uid=fuo.uid
LEFT JOIN firstpoint_organisations fo ON fo.nid=fuo.nid
WHERE u.status=1
AND u.uid > 1 
ORDER BY u.uid 
LIMIT 3
```

You should put an index on `users(status)`, which may give you some benefit if there are enough rows with status != 1

It is quite expected that changing the LIMIT would have no effect, because 70000 rows must be sorted *before* the limit is applied to know *which* rows are the first rows to return - the limit has little effect, except that less rows are returned to the client (less comma IO)

---

I'm a believer in "less code is good", so from a strictly style point of view I have removed non essential code from your query:

- removed `OUTER` because there is no other kind of left join
- removed brackets around join conditions because you don't need 'em

Answer (score 1):

I would use a unique index on u.status,u.uid for that, because mysql has to make a fullscan to look, which entries has status = 1 I think.

I hope it's faster afterwards ;)